# AWS IAM: wildcards in conditions for aws:principalArn

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to make my IAM policy conditional, to allow it to work with an EC2 instance that has definite assumed role. The following syntax works great if I know the id of that instance, sasying it's `i-1111111111111111`:

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::111122223333:assumed-role/MyRole/i-1111111111111111"
      },
    "Action" : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
    "Resource" : "*"
  } ]
}
```

However I want to allow this access for *any* future EC2 instance with the same role. As wildcards do not work in Principal field, I try to specify a wildcarded condition:

```
    "Principal" : "*",
    "Condition": {
      "StringLike": {
        "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:sts::111122223333:assumed-role/MyRole/*"
      }
    },
```

but this does not grant access.

What the correct syntax should be for wildcarded principal?

Comment: Did you try the IAM role ARN? The docs for [aws:PrincipalArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-principalarn) explicitly state: "Do not specify the assumed role session ARN as a value for this condition key."

Comment: Thank you jarmod, but neither `"aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:sts::111122223333:assumed-role/MyRole"` nor `"aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:sts::111122223333:assumed-role/MyRole*"` work. Did you mention something else?

Comment: The documentation I referred to earlier says that "For IAM roles, the request context returns the ARN of the role, not the ARN of the user that assumed the role." Did you test with the IAM role ARN e.g. `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/role-name`?

Comment: No, this does not work too, and the error that AWS reports is that `arn:aws:sts::111122223333:assumed-role/MyRole/i-1111111111111111` is not authorized "because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action". Again, it works if `arn:aws:sts::111122223333:assumed-role/MyRole/i-1111111111111111` is allowed to access directly as hardcoded Principal.

Comment: Have you got anywhere with this @Dmytro? I have exactly the same problem!